# Rewrite rule for subdomain's subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have subdomain test.mydomain.com, Main application is running on test.mydomain.com.

When user visits `http://test.mydomain.com/portal` I need to redirect to `/users/test/cp` sub directory without changing url

I have wrote htaccess but css and javascript are not loading showing 302 response

```
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).mydomain.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?portal/(.*)$ /users/%1/cp/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, small mistake i had done.

```
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).mydomain.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?portal/(.*)$ /users/%1/cp/$1 [L]
```